# Keycloak - map LDAP role to custom realm role & get users by API

Tags: keycloak

**Background:**

I have KeyCloak 19.0.2 with LDAP integration to my company's Active Directory.

I setup role-ldap-mapper to synchronize specific roles from AD. The roles are also correctly assigned to users.

Additionally, I have created some "custom" realm roles. Let's say I have the following realm roles:

- AD_Role1
- AD_Role2
- AD_Role3
- CustomRole1
- CustomRole2

**Expectations:**

I want my application to operate only on custom roles, so I was trying to setup composite role and assign it like:

- AD_Role1 => CustomRole1
- AD_Role2 + AD_Role3 => CustomRole2

It works well - all the roles are available in access_token.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, I also need to query REST API for all users in a specific role. ( i.e. via: /admin/realms/MyRealm/roles/CustomRole1/users )

When I query for AD_Role1 it returns all users correctly. But when I query for CustomRole1, it returns 0 results (because CustomRole1 is inherited).

**So is there a way to (one of?):**

1. Get a list of all users in a specific role?
2. Get a list of all users altogether with their' roles?
3. Create some mappers that will assign users to custom roles based on AD roles during synchronization?